# Why JQuery script does not finish from time to time in ASP.net mcv?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I do have a view (asp.net mvc 4) with some JQuery script.

The part with the form data looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group date">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.selFilterData.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control", id = "StartDate" })
    @Html.Label("Text", new { @class = "form-control", id = "lbltext" })
</div>
```

Depending on the model data I show/hide (with JQuery) the Date-Textbox or the label:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         // save model Data
         var last24h = function () { 
             return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.selFilterData.last24h)); }();
        var TodayDate = function () { 
            return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.selFilterData.TodayDate)); }();
        var SingleDate = function () { 
            return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.selFilterData.SingleDate)); }();

        // Heute
        if (TodayDate == true) {
            $("#StartDate").hide();
            $("#last24h").prop("checked", false);
            $("#SingleDate").prop("checked", false);
            $("#lbltext").show();                              
            $("#lbltext").html("Daten von Heute");
            $("#myHead_last_h").css("font-size", "1.2em");
        }

        // Daten der letzten 24h
        if (last24h == true) {
            $("#StartDate").hide();
            $("#TodayDate").prop("checked", false);
            $("#SingleDate").prop("checked", false);
            $("#StartDate").html("Daten der letzten 24h");
            $("#lbltext").show();
            $("#lbltext").html("Daten der letzten 24h");
        }

        // Datumsauswahl
        if (SingleDate == true) {
            $("#StartDate").show();
            $("#TodayDate").prop("checked", false);
            $("#last24h").prop("checked", false);
            $("#lbltext").hide();                
            $("#StartDate").css('text-align','center');
            $("#StartDate").css("font-size", "1.2em");
            $("#StartDate").css("font-weight", "bold");
        }                                             
    });
```

The menu shows like this in the browser:

[Menu OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGQeJ.jpg)

But sometimes the whole page is fully loaded but both elements are shown:

[Menu not OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ8xx.jpg)

After clicking some where on the page the menu will change to the right settings. I debugged the script but I cant see any difference between a good run and a bad run...

I tried the same with Google Chrome (normally we use IE) - there is everything OK.
I also have 3 Partial views(with table) on my main-view - if I load just 2 of them (doesnt matter which one) it will be alwasy OK.

I dont know where the problem could be...

Comment: Could it be, that the `if`s are conflicting with each other?

Comment: No, I checked the status of each variable and there is always only one TRUE.